# How to create input mask for data capture into File Geodatabase by ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing, file-geodatabase, date

For example if I had a "date" field (d = day digit, m = month letter, y = year digit) I could restrict entries to **dd-mmm-yyyy** instead of any number of different entry types(e.g. **dd-mmm-yy** or **mmm-dd-yy** or etc.) a user might enter.

A real life example using above entry types: User "A" creates a new feature in a feature class and in the "date_created" field user A enters **01-JAN-2015**.  User "B" creates a new feature in the same feature class and in the "date_created" field user B enters **01-JAN-15**. User "C" creates a new feature in the same feature class and in the "date_created" field user C enters  **JAN-01-15**.  These are all valid entries for a "text" type field and 100% accurate for the date but it is incredibly frustrating to SQL. To prevent this I am hoping that ESRI file geodatabase or feature classes have input mask capabilities like Microsoft Access does. Below is an example of input mask for access database.

[image: Example of input masks for access database]

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the software product and version you are using, and the version of the file geodatabase itself.  You'll probably want to clarify what you mean by wanting both "a lot of flexibility" and "only one way" to enter data.

Comment: Are you implying that you want the field to be formatted dd-mmm-yyyy regardless of how the user enters it?

Comment: Would you use a date field instead of a text field? This should provide the required flexibility for the date format.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Good suggestion but as far as I know the "date" field only has one input type (e.g. 1/7/2015).  It will convert most other similar entry types to that one input type, which is nice for data integrity.  But not being able to switch the input type to a more preferred type is what I'm hoping an input mask would allow me to do.  Also, the above date example is just one of many in regards to data type, phone numbers, people names, are other kinds of data I would like an input mask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with ESRI, they do not have this functionality at this point.  Development of this enhancement is unknown.